# How to debug blazor web assembly with multiple project

Tags: debugging, blazor, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger

I have a Blazor web assembly project with multiple applications there. I am newbie to Blazor, my question is how to debug the file inside **wasm.core**. I have tried the way of debugging in Chrome [ALT + SHIFT + D] but no file showing inside f12 inspect. The entire project doesn't have launchSettings.json file.

Any idea how to debug the files?

[debug the page on wasm.core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuiHD.png)

[debug the services on wasm.core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoMJp.png)

Comment: Try using TDD. You can debug your tests.

Comment: Make sure your Wasm.Core project is included in the startup projects with debugging. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2022

Comment: @lohhh Hi, any update of this, have you checked the answer I posted? :)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to debug the code part of the razor file:

[image]

First, launchSettings.json file should be regenerated after you open the solution. If it was not regenerate, you can manually add this file, you can add the below content to the launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:28411",
      "sslPort": 44317
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "<Your Project Name here>": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The structure of where the launchSettings.json file is:

[image]

After that, you need to do something interactive in the opened website to step into the code(What kind of interactive determined by the code you were writing.).

By the way, to select the start up project that you want to debug, you can right click the project, and click "Set as Start Up Project":

[image]

After that, if you press f5, you will start to debug the project.

For more information, you can refer to this official document:

[Debug ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)